# how to set custom order for teams

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working on a program in Laravel

In this program, participants are divided in several teams,

for example, team A to G
That the tandem arrangement, with (A-> B-> C-> D-> E-> F-> G)

For every day a team is selected (as present team) the next day after the team's innings
In this way

its becomes clear that every day who must be present.

Now my question is:

1-what form such teams is to be determined

2-if a team was eliminated from the arrangement did not affect the connected row

3-added a new team and be placed in any position in this row. ex(A->B->Z->C)

this is some part of my code:

teams-people table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teams-people', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order')->unsigned()->nullable();                        
        $table->integer('teams_id')->unsigned()->index();                        
        $table->integer('people_id')->unsigned()->index();                        
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

peoples table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('gender');            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

ORM relation

```
    public function team()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\teams-people','people_id');
}
```

teams-people relation to people:

```
    public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\person', 'people_id');
}
```

**One solution may be to add "next-team" column to team's table to define Which team is the next team ,But I think this can cause problems in cases Such as eliminating a team or add new team and A team can be the next team for two or more team in this way, Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an order relation defined by `order` column (`A` team has `order` 1, `B` team has `2` etc.), you can select next team like this, what will return next Team in the order:

`$team = Team::where('order', '>', <team-A-order>)->first()`

When you add a new team, just [increment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#increment-and-decrement) the order like:

`DB::table('teams')->where('id', '>', $order)->increment('order');`